Javascript media devices web cam not turning off
I am using media devices to access web cam in my web app. I've been using this part of code to stop any media devices which stopped working lately. I've tried querying GPT but none of the solutions are stopping my web cam the indicator in browser tab starts blinking when I'm trying to stop it but it does not turn off completely also the LED light on my laptop is kept turned on until the refresh of the page.
navigator.mediaDevices
                  .getUserMedia({
                    video: true,
                  })
                  .then(function(stream) {
                    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                      track.stop()
                    })
                  })
                  .catch(function(err) {
                    console.error('Error accessing camera:', err)
                  })


Here's the answer: Webcam light doesnt turn off after setting the video constraint to false in webRtc

Every time you call navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() a new MediaStream is created, with new MediaStreamTracks. Closing these new MediaStreamTracks won't close the previous ones.


So what you need is to keep track of your previous MediaStream, and close the VideoTrack from it.


If you think the linked answer solves the issue, then please close-vote as a dupe
